# Portable stream-of-bytes interface for C++

Tags: c++, stream, portability

I work on an [open source portable C++ image compression library](http://charls.codeplex.com). Currently, my API works by exchanging pointers to byte arrays with image data. I would like to support some kind of streaming mode for better performance and memory consumption.

For this, I would like to know if there is an interface or abstract base class (part of the C++ standard libraries) that I can use as an interface to a stream of input bytes, similar to Java's InputStream, or C# Stream. It could be as simple as this:

```
 class inputstream 
 {
      public:
      virtual void readbytes(char*, size_t count) = 0;
 };
```

I could define an interface like this myself, but then I require everybody to implement some kind of adapter to interface to my code, and my flavor of IO error handling, and I would like to avoid that.

Ideally this interface or base class would be already implemented by some existing C++ standard libraries for reading files. If it is not a base class, it should be totally abstract so my users can connect to whatever bytestream they have (platform specific, socket, whatever). I have browsed around in iostream but found nothing that fits the bill. It should be as light weight as possible: Error handling should be defined, but there's no need for seeking the stream.

If there is no such thing (which I fear), is there something like an existing best practice? Like a function pointer with a standard signature, and a contract for error handling? If there are creative solutions that would work in C as well, I am also interested.

**Edit: the key thing is that base class's read() method(s) are virtual.**

Comment: how is the standard iostreams library not meeting your requirements.  It's available pretty much every place you have a c++ compiler, and if your vendor's implementation is quirky, there's the boost version which matches the standard quite closelyh\

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: So far I did not find a base class in there which in which all members are virtual. Also, it is text oriented, with functions like get_line(), which are unneccesary and distractive for my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your library accepts a `std::istream` then it will work with files, memory buffers, and user-defined streams.

Your source of confusion seems to be that `istream` doesn't have any virtual members to override and customize.  This is because `istream` delegates all customizable functionality to `std::streambuf`, which is where you'll find the virtual members.

If you wanted to expose the compression results as a stream, you'd want to derive from `streambuf`.  Conversely, you could accept an `istream` to read from and an `ostream` to store compressed results into.

By accepting an `istream`, your client can supply an `istream` constructed on any `streambuf`, either the library provided `stringbuf` or `filebuf` or a custom version.

Since you don't want to work with textual data but byte streams, perhaps using the `streambuf` directly would be better than using `istream` to wrap it.

Comment: Aaaaah. So that's the missing piece in the puzzle. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ended up standarizing on std::basic_streambuf<char>. That's a level lower than you suggested, but istream did not reall add anything to streambuf. Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Look at stringstream. It does what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plain `std::ifstream`, which is nothing more than a "stream of bytes". Byte extraction is by default byte per byte, and can be used in a kazillion number of different ways:

```
#include <fstream>
    using std::ifstream;

int main()
{
    ifstream stream;
    stream.open("example.jpg", ifstream::binary ); // open raw binary stream
    if( !stream ) // check if stream is ready to be read
        throw runtime_error( "Failed to open file..." );

    char byteBuffer;

    while( stream >> byteBuffer ) // read all bytes until read/extraction fails
    {
        // do something with the byte
    }
    stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps. I understand not *every* platform has a byte-size char, but I'm sure there's some trick that allows you to use a byte-element iostream object (default is `char` or `wchar_t` for the wide classes).

Comment: The issue is that the read() method on std::ifstream and std::fstream are not virtual. At least not in my implementation (VC++), nor have I found documentation that these methods should be virtual. In my scenario, my client code needs to be able to override this.

Comment: Then use composition: make a stream member that you access through your own class interface (that can be virtual if you want). Why would the read function need to be changed? A std::fstream provides pretty much anything one could want. Wrapper functions are easily written I think.

Comment: How do you use an `fstream` to read data that's in memory or coming in through a network connection rather than on disk?

Answer (score 0):

std::fstream sounds like it fits the bill, despite your feeling of its lack of appropriateness, perfectly to me.  Sure it has a seek but its not exactly heavy code.

Comment: The issue is that the read() method on std::ifstream and std::fstream are not virtual. At least not in my implementation (VC++), nor have I found documentation that these methods should be virtual. In my scenario, my client code needs to be able to override this.